# PowerShell GUI / Windows Forms causing script to freeze

Tags: powershell

Below is the fundamentals of the code which is not working.

ISSUE:

- The API request takes a long time to finish which in turn causes the GUI to freeze and script to hang.
- I can run the call manually and it works fine, it just takes a long time.
- I built everything else before indtrocuding this call so the rest of the workflow is working.

  ```
  function myFunc {
      try {
          $status.Text = 'Collecting data'
          $response = myHTTPCall -RequestTimeout 300
      }
      catch {
          Write-Host "An error occurred:"
          Write-Host $_
      }
      $status.Text = 'Done'
  }

  Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
  $main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

  $status = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $status.Text = ""
  $main_form.Controls.Add($status)

  $Btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Btn.Add_Click({
          myFunc
  })

  $main_form.Controls.Add($Btn)
  $main_form.ShowDialog()
  ```

Comment: As for this.. 'The API request takes a long time to finish...', there is nothing Windows proper or Windows PowerShell can do about this. This is an issue with the API specifically or something on the vendor side or something filtering (restricting flow) in your enterprise. for the later, try doing this off your corporate network, if you've not already. Lastly, you ar eonly showing your code wihtout the API name of call, so, leaving us to guess who/what you are dealing with.

Comment: It's an internal tool which you cannot access or test. As I wrote, powershell can deal with it, I can run that call without problems, it is only when the form is used it just lever goes past that point/the gui freezes

Comment: OK, but, this is odd since a form has no control over code, other than a click event, which you are just calling the code behind. Thus should be no different that calling natively, but apparently, it is.  I would suggest refactoring your code a bit to add some measurement for GUI startup, code call, code response, and GUI lock state (meaning put a timer on the form and shut it down after a time period), to see is the varies and by how much on each attempt.

Comment: Perhaps you could use [Start-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) to run the internal tool in the background to keep your gui responsive while waiting for it to finish.

Comment: If you are freezing it's because you're single threaded. Like Theo suggests, use start-job to create a powershell job which is as good as it gets to multi-threading and preventing your GUI from freezing. The freeze happens because powershell is busy of course.

Comment: I absolutely hear what you are saying, and I will consider using a job, but what confuses me is that this call does finish in 1-2 min when running that piece of code only and it NEVER finishes when forms are in the picture. So I am talking about a permanent freeze/crash

Comment: I did go forward using jobs for the heave duties, and it worked fine. 
Thanks